# Finding translation Matrix using SVD in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix, svd

I'm trying to find translation and rotation of an image using SVD. to find the corresponding points between the 2 pictures I used template matching. the matches are perfect but the matrix that are being calculated are as follows:

```
essential matrix [-2.039822534788701e-019, 0.002807993863143686, 0.4097425267405184;
  -0.002807993863143689, 4.920343025661717e-018, -0.3264091934071822;
  -0.443438453098242, 0.3601051197649062, 1];


SVD components:
u [0.2992078577907173, -0.7163016363498457, 0.6303860908989213;
  -0.2371264394987113, 0.5841077281400203, 0.7762662002288702;
  0.9242541368730539, 0.3817461560901925, -0.004915565421039324]
vt [-0.3294400799571679, 0.2686417102753414, 0.9051523988910125;
  -0.7094007484184662, 0.5622100799500159, -0.425053413285809;
  -0.623072878450936, -0.7821454196649983, 0.005360096634284935]
w [1.242058875140318;
  0.24093729282062;
  4.072587793310116e-019]


Rotation matrix
[-0.8410132227937885, -0.1324074233048742, 0.5245617535998686;
  -0.1230242455085329, -0.8973836265311757, -0.4237542470003247;
  -0.5268413367448126, 0.4209167389015554, -0.7384221724795504]
Translation matrix
[-0.2145634591193726, 0.1688602189163624, -0.8498187651237489;
  0.176149983599124, -0.1386627332926497, 0.6923530041855173;
  0.3013810351332639, -0.2425071529534591, 0.3532261924120222]
```

this is how i calculated translation and rotation matrices:

```
cv::SVD decomp = cv::SVD(fundamentalMatrix);
cv::Mat R1 = decomp.u * cv::Mat(Wt) * decomp.vt;
cv::Mat t1 = decomp.u * cv::Mat(W) * cv::Mat(w3) * ut;
```

source for the formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication

but according to the formulas i should get 0 in diagonals in the translation matrix.

also the translation in the image is exactly 12 pixels on x axis and 6 pixels on y axis.

but the calculated values are way off...

EDIT: To clarify, I am trying to estimate the camera rotation and translation in 3D using stereoscopic images in sequential frames.

Comment: why not directly use the `findEssentialMat`, `decomposeEssentialMat` and `recoverPose` functions? Also read the notes in the decompose function: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga54a2f5b3f8aeaf6c76d4a31dece85d5d&gsc.tab=0

Comment: The way the question is worded, it's unclear to me if you are trying to estimate the 3D rotation and translation that transforms between the coordinate systems of the cameras used to capture the images, or if you are just interested in finding the 2D rotation and translation that can be used to align one image with the other.

Comment: Thank you @Amro, I will look into them. I'm not sure if recover pose returns 3D rotation and translation or 2D since it does not say it in documentation but i will give it a try.